# Angular Element gets destroyed on mat-tab-group when new tab is added

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-tab-group that gets populated from an array. I add new items to the array dynamically and the content of the tabs are Angular Elements components.

When I add a new element everything works fine and I see the new element added, but I add a new element, the previous element gets destroyed and the tab content appears empty.

I have inspected an element when it's added and I see it works perfectly, but when I add a new element, I can see the previous one disappears from the DOM.

I have tried adding regular text into the tabs instead of Angular Elements components and everything works as expected and I can move back and forward on the tabs.

The tab group HTML is this:

```html
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTab">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index" [label]="tab.name">
    <div [innerHTML]="tab.content"></div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The code that adds a new tab is this:

```js
this.tabs.push({
  name: this.options[opt].name,
  content: this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<osm-'+this.options[opt].content+'></osm-'+this.options[opt].content+'>')
} as MainTab);
this.selectedTab = this.tabs.length -1;
```

The `options` array is a list of the possible new tabs that can be added:

```js
options = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Sell', content: 'sell'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Admin', content: 'admin'}
];
```

And the `osm-sell` and the `osm-admin` components have been created as Angular Elements components (as described in [this guide](https://juristr.com/blog/2019/04/intro-to-angular-elements/).

All the code is on [Github](https://github.com/igorosabel/TPV).

The expected result should be what happens on the first step, a new tab is added with the component in its content, but it gets destroyed when adding a new one.

A live test is on https://tpv.osumi.es

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Because pushing to an array triggers a change detection, and your tabs aren't tracked properly, so the framework re-renders them.

Try using a custom track by function :

```
*ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index; trackBy: customTB"
```

In your TS

```
customTB(index, tab) {
  return tab.id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but it's still not working. I have added your code and some console.logs and it's not working. Putting console.log on that customTB function gives me this:

0
main.component.ts:40 {id: 1559661519258, name: "Venta", content: SafeHtmlImpl}
1
main.component.ts:40 {id: 1559661543015, name: "Admin", content: SafeHtmlImpl}

So the comparison is not working, it is testing the index against the object, isn't it?

I have updated the live site and the Github repo.

Thanks again!

Comment: @IñigoGorosabel that's on me, I was head deep in another similar issue and posted the wrong signature. I have edited my answer, can you test it now ?

Comment: sorry but still nothing, exactly the same behaviour. I have updated the live site and the Github repo. If I can't get this working I will try dynamic component injection instead, but I would like to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: @IñigoGorosabel you should provide a sandbox that can be played with. Having just an exemple of the issue without the code that goes with it is kind of useless ...

Comment: Hi! Sorry I haven't been able to answer sooner. I made a StackBlitz with this code and it breaks the same way: https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-osumi-tpv Hope you can find something ;)